# Do the FAA 8130-3 and EASA Form 1 have a validity period?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, easa-regulations

I have investigated both FAA and EASA regulations and am unable to conclude if there is any restriction or limitation to the validity of an FAA 8130-3 or EASA Form 1 release. So technically, any of these release documents remain valid for as long as the end-user is willing to accept them.

My question refers to aircraft components without any Time/Life limitations so OC/CM. This is just in case someone deems it relevant.

Is there any contradictory information that someone can provide or am I assessing this correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An 8130-3 does not list an expiration date, but that does not mean that the item can always be returned to service regardless of how long ago the tag was issued. Having the 8130-3 and not installing the item does not relieve the owner from compliance with any AD's issued since the tag was issued, for example. You may also run into a component that had an 8130-3 issued a long time ago with the expectation that it would be put back into service, but is put into storage for a long time, and the proper steps for long term storage of the item as per the manufacturer are not followed. The tag doesn't let you skip that kind of thing.